# Histogram using arrays not counting int 10 in final histogram

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods, histogram

So I'm trying to basically have a program where I input a set of numbers separated by a space,

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 1 31 31 45 98 99 100 500,

and when I go over 100, the program plots asterisks based on what tens range they fall in (1-10, 11-20, etc.)

However, the int 10 does not get plotted on my histogram. I've toyed and tinkered with less than or equal to, different indices starting int, etc, etc. but I think that the problem is rooted in my `getData(int[] someArray)` method, but I'm not sure what.

Code:

```
public class DistributionChart1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 10;
        int[] ranges = new int[size]; // each entry represents a range of values

        getData(ranges); // pass the entire array into the method

        displayChart(ranges);

        System.out.println("\nSee you later!!");

    } // end of main

    public static void getData(int[] someArray) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a series of numbers between 1 and 100. Separate each number with a space.");
        System.out.println("Signal the end by entering a number outside " + "of that range and then press enter.");
        System.out.print("Go: ");

        // reads an arbitrary number of integers that are in the range 1 to 100
        int n;
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            n = scan.nextInt();
            if (n > 100) {
                break;
            }

            int index = n / 10;

            if (index == 10) {
                index -= index;
                break;
            }
        // for each integer read in, determine which range it is in and increment the
        // corresponding element in the array

            someArray[index] += 1;

        }

        scan.close();
    }// end of getData

    public static void displayChart(int[] someArray) {
        // Print chart title with your name
        System.out.println("\nDistribution Chart By simonshampoo" + "\n===================================");
        // Print histogram.

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int beginning = i * 10 + 1;
            int ending = beginning + 9;
            System.out.print(beginning + "-" + ending + "\t|");

            for (int j = 0; j < someArray[i]; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    } //
```

Output:

```
Enter a series of numbers between 1 and 100. Separate each number with a space.
Signal the end by entering a number outside of that range and then press enter.
Go: 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 1 31 31 45 98 99 100 500

Distribution Chart By simonshampoo
===================================
1-10    |*
11-20   |**
21-30   |**
31-40   |****
41-50   |***
51-60   |**
61-70   |**
71-80   |**
81-90   |**
91-100  |****

See you later!!
```

I have both 10 and 1, both fall into range 1-10, but I removed the 1 from the set and no asterisk shows up, so it's definitely the 10. Thank you very much

Comment: `index -= index;`? Why not `index = 0;`? Why do it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
int index = n / 10;
```

For n = 1-9, that calculates `index = 0`, i.e. the value should be counted in the 1st bucket, i.e. bucket 0.

For n = 10-19, that calculates `index = 1`, i.e. the value should be counted in the 2nd bucket, i.e. bucket 1.

As you can see, n = 10 is counted in the wrong bucket. The same goes for 20, 30, 40, ... 90, and is why you needed to ignore 100 with that extra `if 
(index == 10)`, even though it's supposed to count that too.

See for yourself:

- Try entering `9 999` and `1-10` has `*`
- Try entering `10 999` and `11-20` has `*` (Oops).
- Try entering `100 999` and there will be no stars (Oops).

Your code should be:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    if (n < 1 || n > 100) {
        break;
    }
    int index = (n - 1) / 10;
    someArray[index]++;
}
```

With the code, you can end the input by typing `0`, as the instructions say you can, but wasn't working in the question code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that deleting questions on here isn't recommended, but I've figured it out. It's because I put a `break` in my `if ( index == 10)`.

Comment: I was planning to mark my own answer as correct, but I can't seem to do so. can a moderator please do so? thank you and sorry for inconvenience

Comment: I meant ```if (index == 10) ```. sorry

Comment: Nope, not the reason.